# FFmpeg: cutting and merging videos added some freezed frames in between

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to cut the original video in three parts and applying effect on 1st and 3rd part and then concatenating all parts together. But this introduces few blank frames in between. Please help.

My command for cutting video in three parts is :

```
    var command1 = "-i $path -ss $fadeInStart -t ${fadeInDuration+2} ${getFilePath(partVideoList[0])}"
    var command2 = "-i $path -ss ${fadeInDuration+2} -to 00:04:02 -c:v copy -c:a copy ${getFilePath(partVideoList[1])}"
    var command3 = "-i $path -ss ${fadeOutStart-2} -t ${fadeOutStart-2+fadeOutDuration} ${getFilePath(partVideoList[2])}"
```

Comment: When you streamcopy `-c:v copy -c:a copy`, results many not be as expected. What's wrong with doing fade-in+out in one command?

Comment: @Gyan it's taking too much time if i go for fadeIn/Out in a single go.!! For a 4 min Video(720p) , its taking 22 minutes i.e - speed = 0.3x